# How to get handle to container and/or the browser

Tags: javascript, .net, com, activex, ole

Hi I have simple COM type implemented in .NET. It is not an activeX control. This type is instantiated through javascript using the ActiveXObject("TypeName").

Now, in the .NET code, how to get the Browser information? Note that the COM type is not a control, otherwise, Control.GetContainer() would give me what I need.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Found answer with little bit of googling around.

Implement the IObjectWithSite interface which defines SetSite() and GetSite() methods. When ActiveX object is created the web browser calls the IObjectWithSite.SetSite() and passes handle to the site. It is up to the usercode to keep hold on the site and use it as needed.

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx